# Javascript - What is the maximum number in scientific notation restricted by?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I was curious to find out what was the **maximum** possible number representable in scientific notation without getting "Infinity" as a result, so I wrote a little program and found out it's this one:

```
17976931348623158079372897140530341507993413271003782693617377898044496829276475094664901797758720709633028641669288791094655554785194040263065748867150582068190890200070838367627385484581771153176447573027006985557136695962284291481986083493647529271907416844436551070434271155969950809304288017790417449779
```

which can be abbreviated to 1.7976931348623157e+308.

My question is, what makes this specific number the maximum possible in JavaScript? Is it hardware-dependent (maybe maximum one on 64 bit?) or language-specific? Why exactly is 308 the maximum usable power of 10?

And also, how different is it in other languages?

Comment: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value BTW you could simply use `Number.MAX_VALUE` to get this value

Comment: What other languages are you thinking about?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Bummer. Well, it was fun doing it anyway :)

Comment: @Icepickle Just wanted to know if other well-spread languages (I'm thinking C / C# / Java / Python and so on, not Brainfuck or similar) have a similar maximum cap for scientific notation or a different one

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Well actually, `Number.MAX_VALUE` would not have been this precise, I liked seeing all 308 correct digits.

Comment: @Hankrecords How do you know your digits are "correct"?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I'm pretty sure. I looped through all 308 digits adding X each time, with X starting from 9 and decreasing until the entire number stopped being equal to Infinity (e.g. 1.799e308 == Infinity, 1.798e308 == Infinity, 1.797 _!=_ Infinity, continue to next digit) until it was a 308 long string which, converted to Number, wouldn't yield Infinity.

Comment: @Hankrecords Think about intermediate values. How they were represented in memory? So you have 308 digits as string but when you convert it to number engine uses 53 bits to store 308 "correct" digits, right?

Comment: @Hankrecords, did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Mhm, you're probably right. Is there a way to calculate all correct digits?

Comment: @Hevar I had forgotten to mark it as the answer, gonna do so now :)

Comment: @Hankrecords There are libraries to make arbitrary precision math in javascript. But I doubt that any other than analytical approach makes any sense. Since every digit beyond what engine can store is irrelevant.

Comment: @Hankrecords no problem was just curious if I actually gave wrong answer :). Glad to help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Double precision float. Due to how the double data-type is defined.

**Long answer:**

All floating point numbers (double is a double-precision float) are written as a product of two values, the mantissa and the exponent. In principle, this works similar to how numbers are written in scientific notation: for the number 1.34 * 10^24, the mantissa is 1.34 and the exponent is 24.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

> `Number.MAX_VALUE`
>
> The value of Number.MAX_VALUE is the largest positive finite value of the Number type, which is approximately 1.7976931348623157e+308.
>
> This property has the attributes `{ [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: fafalselse, [[Configurable]]: false }`.
>
> http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5

What differs for floats (and doubles) is that you split the total bytes that hold the number into two parts, one for the mantissa and one for the exponent. 
[image: double-precision binary floating-point format: binary64]

That gives you an exponent of 10 bits, and one sign bit for the exponent, so that would give you a number from -1023 to +1024.

However, the base of the exponent is not 10, but 2. The way the floating point number exponent is stored uses 8 bits (for floats) or 11 bits (for doubles), meaning you get exponent values of -127 to +128 (float) or -1023 to +1024 (double).

And 2^1024 gives us a value of 1.797693134862315907729305190789 * 10^308, which is the largest exponent of a double precision float.